# Handle Null values without Case

Tags: sql-server

Hi I had a Table called `Details` which contains column `Day1` with datatype as `Int`. 
Now if the Column `Day1` contains any number then I want to display `100` else if it contains null I want to display null only. 
Apart from writing below case statement is there any more simpler way to do it?:

```
Case when Day1=10 /*(Apart from 0 it can have any value including null)*/ then 100 else Day1
```

I had around 31 columns I dont want to write case for each and every column.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly No, if you are thinking of using `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` function but you can modify your `CASE` expression to be like below

```
Case when Day1 > 0 or Day1 IS NULL then 100 else Day1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check for NULL in the CASE-Statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Day1 IS NULL THEN Day1 ELSE 100 END AS Day1 FROM Details
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't exactly get what's your intention of writing such a query, but nevertheless, this case will do it.

```
CASE WHEN Day1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 100 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want to check whether it is a number or not, `ISNUMERIC` comes to mind:

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Day1) = 1 THEN 100 ELSE NULL END
```

, but I think simply writing

```
CASE WHEN Day1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 100 END
```

or

```
IIF(ISNUMERIC(Day1) = 1, 100, NULL)
```

is more intuitive (see how you don't need a `CASE` in this case? :-))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer:

```
IIF(Day1 IS NULL, NULL, 100)
```

or you can make a user-defined function to do the same thing even more concisely (works with all versions of SQL Server):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc(@Day int)
RETURNS int
RETURN (CASE WHEN @Day IS NOT NULL THEN 100 ELSE NULL END)
```

Usage:

```
SELECT MyFunc(Day1), MyFunc(Day2)
```